# How do I build everything?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no Makefile in the root of ros-pkg!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9038/how-do-i-build-everything?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS packages live in a federated space where's there's no central list of things to be built. For reasons of (disk) space and time, usually you just want to build the things that you're working with. E.g., if you're using the pr2_2dnav_gazebo package, which brings up a navigation stack in simulation, you can build all the pieces you need with rosmake:

```
rosmake pr2_2dnav_gazebo
```

Having said that, if you really want to build everything, you can use rosmakeall:

```
rosmakeall
```

It will build all packages in your ROS_ROOT and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH directories. Note that this will take about 90 minutes and consume about 1GB on disk. As of now, rosmakeall also runs all the tests for each package. It will eventually be modified to not run tests.

---

Originally posted by [mwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/28/mwise/) with karma: 208 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Note that this will take about 90 minutes

What type of PC produces this result?

---

Originally posted by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2